# QEventDispatcher: Failed to create QEventDispatcherWin32 internal window: 1407

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, qevent

We've a web app that runs wkhtmltopdf.exe in its own process to convert an html string to a pdf file.

On the live server it fails to complete and when the process is killed off reports the error:

```
QEventDispatcher: Failed to create QEventDispatcherWin32 internal window: 1407

Loading pages (1/6)
[>                                                           ] 0%
[======>                                                     ] 10%

QEventDispatcher: Failed to create QEventDispatcherWin32 internal window: 1407
```

The same code runs ok from the cmd line and on another support server.